# Cell phone service providers in France with English customer support

Tags: france, cellphones, english-language

Which major cell phone providers provide English customer support in France?  Not speaking French, I find it extremely daunting to deal with them and I already had some rather bad experiences with a French-language-only provider.

Comment: The UK network "3" does not charge anything extra to use your phone in France, or indeed, many other countries. However you are supposed to use your phone in the UK from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

### French Orange Speaks English

It would seem that [Orange has a dedicated customer support line catering to English-speaking customers](http://www.orange.com/en/Footer/contacts/clients/all-customer-contacts). Quoting from the linked page:

> Orange France has opened a  customer  service to cater needs of  English-speaking customers living in France. It now includes a technical support helpline in English.
>
> The number  can be reached  from France or abroad **+33 (0)9 69 36 39 00**<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup>(calls are charged at your telephone company rates)

Since Orange provides landlines, TV and mobile services, you might be in luck with them.

This English-speaking customer support line from Orange is mentioned in several expatriate forum posts on web. Most of which bring positive feedback [saying that when contacted, the customer service was extremely useful](http://www.expatforum.com/expats/france-expat-forum-expats-living-france/90140-orange-english-customer-support.html#post612568):

> I just had to call Orange as we had an Internet problem and they gave me a number for support in English - 09 69 36 39 00. Very helpful people indeed, and I can do all the transactions on any Orange account through this number including moving our phone and ADSL to our new address.
>
> Kudos where its due

### Other Alternatives

In my opinion your best bet is to approach a company with physical shops manned by physical people. This will increase your chances of finding an English-speaking employee to whom you could ask for help. Such physical network operators are: Orange, SFR, Free Mobile and Bouygues Télécom.

There has recently been a boom of low-cost mobile operators in France, all of which save money by dealing with customer support using online forums and call centres which cost a fortune to call. Personally I wouldn't hope to find an English-speaking customer support line employee of any such services.